# TextView: How to listen or handle space bar key event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Okay so 'return' is 'insertNewline', I love that,  but where in god's green earth is the  insertSpace?

So i'm trying to invoke a spellcheck (for a keyword) after the user completes the word  (aka, when they hit space bar or return ). But daddy needs to detect space-bar.  Heres the textView delegate method i'm implementing...

```
/* listen to commands */ 
-(BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    if (@selector(insertNewline:) == aSelector) {
    // does something 
    result = YES; 
    return result; 
}
return result;
```

Comment: You really should consider that not all languages use whitespace word boundaries and you have failed to account for any forms of punctuation (a.k.a. Non-white space word boundaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the delegate method of *UITextView* as follows to achieve this...

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        //code when return key pressed.
    }
    else if([text isEqualToString:@" "])
    {
        //code when space key pressed.
    }
    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the space bar will insert a unichar equivalent to the one above. You cannot control what language and keyboard and input method a user chooses. ( or should not try to generally ) also, the Op did not ask for iOS.