# how to detect space key in NSTextField

Tags: macos, autocomplete, nstextfield

i have used one NSTextField and i want to implement autocomplete in which i want to detect space key while there are multiple words in my NSTextField.

I have used this method doCommandBySelector but it does not have any method for space detecting while it has methods for tab , delete and back key.

For ex :

```
if (commandSelector == @selector(deleteBackward:))
{
    backspaceKey = YES;
}
```

please help me on how to detect space key. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using UITextView's delegate to check for what was the input as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081312/textview-how-to-listen-or-handle-space-bar-key-event)?

Comment: `OS X` doesn't use `UITextView`; maybe you mean `NSTextView`?